# How to hide some component based on some flag in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to hide some component based on some flag in react js.
I have an App component where I have Login and other components, I want to hide the other component until Login components `this.state.success` is `false` and on click of a button I am changing the sate, but it's not working, I am new to react,

My App Class compoenent -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "../../logo.svg";
// import Game from "../Game/Game";
import Table from "../Table/Table";
import Form from "../Table/Form";
import Clock from "../Clock/Clock";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "../Login/Login";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    success: false
  };

  removeCharacter = index => {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      characters: characters.filter((character, i) => {
        return i !== index;
      })
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = character => {
    this.setState({ characters: [...this.state.characters, character] });
  };

  handleSuccess() {
    this.setState({ success: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { characters, success } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <span className="Span-inline">App</span>
          <Clock time={new Date()} />
        </header>
        <Login success={success} handleSuccess={this.handleSuccess} />
        {success && (
          <div className="container">
            <h1>React Tutorial</h1>
            <p>Add a character with a name and a job to the table.</p>
            <Table
              characterData={characters}
              removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter}
            />
            <h3>Add New character</h3>
            <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
          </div>
        )}

        {/* <Game /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Login component -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Greeting from "./Greeting";
import LogoutButton from "./LogoutButton";
import LoginButton from "./LoginButton";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      name: "",
      success: false
    };
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    this.setState({ success: true });
  }
  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
    this.setState({ success: false });
  }
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    const name = this.state.name;
    // const successLogin = this.state.success;

    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting
          isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
          name={name}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

please guide me on what I am doing wrong. 
Why sometime debuggers do not trigger in react component?

Comment: It seems you handleSuccess is not triggered to set state as true

Comment: call handlesuccess function from login component

Comment: @KOTIOS yes correct,

Comment: @JavascriptCoder so whats the issue now ?

Comment: is there any error

Comment: @KOTIOS I am not able to catch how to trigger its state, inside the handleLoginClick i am changing the setState for success but how can send this to again parent.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Gotcha , declare the handleLoginClick  in parent component and pass that as props to child , then once you change the state in handleLoginClick  the parent component state will change hence the state change will trigger

Comment: @KOTIOS thanks, this makes more sense let me refactor it.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  handleLoginClick() {
   this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
   this.setState({ success: true });
   this.props.handleSuccess()
  }
```

do like this

```
 <Login success={success} handleSuccess= 
 {this.handleSuccess} />
```

bind this function

Comment: Thanks now i am able to trigger this function.

Comment: <Login success={success} handleSuccess= 
 {this.handleSuccess} /> .bind(this) is not required. It works without that

Comment: inside my handleSuccess() {
    alert("handle success called");
    this.setState({ success: true });
  } How can i toggle this value, i tried this.setState({ success: !this.state.success }); but this is not working any feedback

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of example I have used functional stateless component here. You can use Class component all upto you.

```
const conditionalComponent = (props) => {
    let condition = true;
    return (
    {condition && <div><h1>Hello world</h1></div>}
    }
```

Instead of directly giving condition you can even call function which returns a boolean value.

Comment: This is an answer to the title of question. But I guess you were looking for something else i.e componenet interaction(passing data between components). It can be parent to child or child to parent or siblings

Comment: For passing data from child to parent component you have to give a callback function in parent component and pass that callback function as props to the child component. Then that function passed as props to the child will be utilized to pass info to parent and it'll be handled by parent. That's why it's called as callback